# package io.tus.java.client does not exist

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to add this to me github project:

```
https://github.com/tus/tus-android-client
```

Added gradle and don't get any issues with it:

```
implementation 'io.tus.android.client:tus-android-client:0.1.5'
```

However, trying to run the example code and some of the imports fail, but not others.

```
import io.tus.android.client.TusPreferencesURLStore; // Works fine
import io.tus.java.client.TusClient; // error: package io.tus.java.client does not exist
import io.tus.java.client.TusUpload; // error: package io.tus.java.client does not exist
import io.tus.java.client.TusUploader; // error: package io.tus.java.client does not exist
```

Comment: *tus-android-client is a library meant to be used in addition to tus-java-client*

Comment: Thank you, that's the problem.

Comment: I know, they explain it in the readme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include the java client in gradle too:

```
implementation 'io.tus.android.client:tus-android-client:0.1.5'
implementation 'io.tus.java.client:tus-java-client:0.4.0'
```